# Changing UISwitch border thickness?

Tags: ios, uiswitch

I'm using a UISwitch in my project and have successfully changed the color of the border using `switch.tintColor`. However, the stroke is a bit thick - is there a way to change the width of this border on the UISwitch?

Comment: Interesting question. I need the same but can't do this =(
Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

Hi you could set the layer border of the switch which will provide the needed customisation for you like this:

```
switch.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
switch.layer.cornerRadius = 16.0;
switch.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow use editor tools to give beter look for you answers